# How to rewrite WebDav http Destination request header on Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, webdav

With configs below, GET, PUT, MKCOL and stuff works fine but MOVE and COPY does not.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;

    charset     utf-8;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;

    auth_pam "WebDav auth";
    auth_pam_service_name "nginx";

    location /dav/ {
        autoindex on;
        client_body_temp_path /var/www/tmp;

        rewrite ^/dav/(.*)$ /dav/$remote_user/$1 break;

        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
        create_full_put_path on;
    }
}
```

Debug log tells that 'http copy to' was not rewritten, then failed to open it, returns 500 error. I think I need to rewrite destination http request header and try it by:

```
set $destination $http_destination;
if ($destination ~ ^(http://www.foobar.test/dav)/(.*)$) {
    set $destination $1/$remote_user/$2;
    set $http_destination $destination;
}
```

but it does not work too. Could you tell me how to work WebDav with rewrite directive?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for noise. self solved, by using [headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_input_headers). Whole simple config is:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;
    charset     utf-8;

    auth_pam "WebDav auth";
    auth_pam_service_name "nginx";

    location /dav/ {
        set $destination $http_destination;
        if ($destination ~ ^(http://www.foobar.test/dav)/(.*)$) {
            set $destination $1/$remote_user/$2;
            more_set_input_headers "Destination: $destination";
        }

        rewrite ^/dav/(.*)$ /dav/$remote_user/$1 break;

        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
        create_full_put_path on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this.  I had a similar issue using NGINX as an https proxy to backend IIS server running WebDAV over http.

The destination header in the MOVE request that was being passed was the https:// address but I was receiving a 400 error from the backend server since it was running over http.  I needed to modify the Destination header from https:// to http:// so used the following

```
 set $destination $http_destination;
    if ($destination ~ ^(https://webdav.mydomain.com)/(.*)$) {
        set $destination "http://webdav.mydomain.com/$2";
        more_set_input_headers "Destination: $destination";
    }
```

This allowed successful MOVE requests